# TSQL-Join on own table, selecting the latest row only

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table `tbl_Partner` (shortened) with two "duplicate" partners:

```
RecordID (GUID) | RISEID (varchar(40)) | UpdateCounter(int) | etc. ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012 | RISE123 | 0
87564321-9012-3456-7890-123456789012 | RISE123 | 1
-- other partners with different updatecounters etc.
```

Now I need a view which has the latest data for each partner (highest UpdateCounter) but the first RecordID (lowest UpdateCounter)

I tried this SQL already:

```
select 
(select top 1 recordid from tbl_partner p2 where p2.riseid=p1.riseid order by p2.updatecounter ASC) as RecordID
, riseid, updatecounter
from tbl_partner p1
order by riseid
```

I get:

```
RecordID (GUID) | RISEID (varchar(40)) | UpdateCounter(int)
-----------------------------------------------------------
12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012 | RISE123 | 0 --(old data)
12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012 | RISE123 | 1 --(new correct data with the first RecordID)
-- other rows/columns omitted
```

How can I select the latest row for each RecordID/RiseID only? (UpdateCounter=1 in this example)

**For the record:** UpdateCounter can be something else than 1 of course and there are other datasets with different values. So I cannot use a simple `WHERE updatecounter>0`.

Comment: What does your required output look like? Give us some more sample data too please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.RecordID,t1.RISEID,t2.UpdateCounter
FROM
   tbl_Partner t1
      inner join
   tbl_Partner t2
      on
          t1.RISEID = t2.RISEID
      left join
   tbl_Partner t1_anti
      on
          t1.RISEID = t1_anti.RISEID and
          t1_anti.UpdateCounter < t1.UpdateCounter
      left join
   tbl_Partner t2_anti
      on
          t1.RISEID = t2_anti.RISEID and
          t2_anti.UpdateCounter > t2.UpdateCounter
where
    t1_anti.RISEID is null and
    t2_anti.RISEID is null
```

It's not clear if you want rows to appear for items where only a single row has a particular `RISEID`. If not, add an extra condition into the join between `t1` and `t2`, such that the `UpdateCounter` is higher on `t2`.

The two outer joins are to ensure that there is no earlier row than `t1` (`t1_anti`) and no later row than `t2` (`t2_anti`). In the `WHERE` clause, we ensure that those joins were unsuccessful.

---

Alternate one, using slightly more modern style:

```
;With OrderedRows as (
    Select RecordID,RISEID,UpdateCounter,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RISEID ORDER BY UpdateCounter ASC) as rnEarly,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RISEID ORDER BY UpdateCounter DESC) as rnLate
    from tbl_Partner
)
SELECT t1.RecordID,t1.RISEID,t2.UpdateCounter
FROM
   OrderedRows t1
       inner join
   OrderedRows t2
       on
            t1.RISEID = t2.RISEID
WHERE
    t1.rnEarly = 1 and
    t2.rnLate = 1
```

which may require fewer scans on the table.

Comment: Looks correct on the first try. I need all partners who all have different RiseIDs. It should have only one row for each partner with the latest datarow, but the RecordID of the first datarow.

Comment: almost finished writing your second solution. +1 for that part

Answer (score 0):

Select Max UpdateCounter

```
 select distinct(
 (select top 1 recordid from tbl_partner p2 where p2.riseid=p1.riseid p2.updatecounter ASC
 ) )as RecordID,(select  Max(updatecounter) from tbl_partner p2 where p2.riseid=p1.riseid   ) as MaxUpdateCounter , riseid  from tbl_partner p1
```